# Looping through object and blanking out fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this constant to hold all dates fields:

```
DATE_FIELDS = [:a_effective_on, :a_expire_on,
                    :field_effective_on, :field_expire_on,
                    :line_manager_effective_on, :line_manager_expire_on,
                    :officer_effective_on, :officer_expire_on,
                    :regional_effective_on, :regional_expire_on]
```

I want to loop over an object and remove a date if it has a value.

Is this valid?:

```
@copy_to.DATE_FIELDS.each do |_date|
# remove dates  here
end
```

I am getting a `nil class for id` error.

Comment: I was getting a nil class for id error

Comment: What is `@copy_to`, what does it hold, and you can not call `array` on object

Comment: It holds all those date fields from the constants array. Plus some other data but I just want to loop over the dates

Comment: @user3437721 Can you show some example of `@copy_to`, I have solution, but I need to know how your object looks like, is it `ActiveRecord`, `Hash`, .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATE_FIELDS.each do |field|
  @copy_to.send("#{field}=".to_sym, nil) if @copy_to.send(field) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put a constant in your class like this, it exists at the class level.  Access it with `YourClassName::DATE_FIELDS` if you're outside the class, or just `DATE_FIELDS` if you're inside the class.

This is how i would do it:

```
#instance method in your class
def clear_all_date_fields
  atts = {}
  DATE_FIELDS.each{|f| atts[f] = nil}
  self.attributes = atts
end
```

Now you can do

```
@copy_to.clear_all_date_fields
```

note that this doesn't save @copy_to.  You can save it afterwards, or put the save into the method (though i think it's better to have it not saving automatically).